# Python 2.7 Tkinter how to change text color of a button's text

Tags: python, button, text, colors, tkinter

button1 = Button(root,text='Revert image',foreground = "red",compound="center")

This type of code is not working. it says  unknown option "-foreground".

This is the whole code that works -

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
def change():
   label.config(text="Hey dude !!")
   label.config(image = img1,background='blue',foreground='yellow')
def click():
         if button1.instate(["disabled"]):
                label.config(image = img1,background='yellow',foreground='green')
                button1.state(['!disabled'])
                button.state(['disabled'])
         else:
                label.config(image = img,background='yellow',foreground='green')
                button1.state(['disabled'])
                button.state(['!disabled'])
root = Tk()
label = Label(root)
img=PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Desktop\\x.gif')
img1= PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Desktop\\y.gif')
img2 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Desktop\\z.gif')
button = Button(root)
button.pack()
button1 = Button(root,text='Revert image',compound="center")
img2_small = img2.subsample(30,80)
button.config(image=img2_small,text='Change image',compound='center')
button1.state(["disabled"])
button1.pack()
label.pack()
button.config(command=click)
button1.config(command = click)
label.config(image = img,background='yellow',foreground='green')
label.config(text = 'Hey dude watsup ?? Are you in a need help ?')
label.config(compound = 'left',wraplength=100,font=('Courier',20,'bold'))
label.after(5000,change)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

so taking a look right [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) you can see that the "foreground" and "fg" option is the same. But this is only the case in the new version of tkinter for python3, if you are using an older version for python2.7 you have to use the "fg" option.

```
btn = Button(root, fg='red') #Creates a button with red text
```

If you would like to change the text color afterwards you can achieve this by using the config function:

```
btn.config(fg='blue') #Changes the text color to blue
```

I hope this clears things up a bit.
keep coding ;D

Answer (score 2):

Because you are doing global imports (rarely ever a good idea), and because you import ttk after tkinter. Both libraries define a `Button` widget, so the ttk `Button` is overriding the tkinter `Button`. The ttk `Button` has no `foreground`option.

You should stop using global imports to eliminate this problem:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
...
root = tk.Tk()
...
tk.Button(...)
```

Comment: thanks :)
but why exactly this problem happened ? so what i imported the whole library it means my code efficiency was not good but what is the reason behind the problem ?

Comment: @Vivekkumarpathak: the reason behind the problem is that the two libraries each define `Button`, but they are different. Once supports `foreground`, one doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I use fg

```
button1 = tk.Button(root, text='hello', fg='red')
```

edit: hm, actually, both `fg` and `foreground` work for me.  If you don't bother with the color, does everything else work?  It may be that some other error is propagating down.  Here is an example of a simple Hello World program using tkinter.  See if it works for you.  I think the capitalization of tkinter has changed between Python 2 and 3.  This is for Python 3.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.TVB1 = tk.StringVar(self, value='hello, there')

        B1 = tk.Button(self)
        # this is an example of how you can define parameters after
        # defining the button
        B1["textvariable"] = self.TVB1
        B1["command"] = self.say_hi
        B1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.TVE1 = tk.StringVar(self, value='wubwub')
        E1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.TVE1)
        E1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # and this is how you can define parameters while defining
        # the button
        Quit = tk.Button(self, text='QUIT', fg='red',
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        Quit.grid(row=2,column=0)

    def say_hi(self):
        print(self.TVB1.get())
        self.TVB1.set(self.TVE1.get())


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Still no luck . it says - NameError: name 'tk' is not defined.

Comment: everything works fine if i don't try to change color using fg/foreground.

Comment: in the above example I had imported tkinter as tk, a standard practice when working with libraries like tkinter.  Take no offense, but I'm going to assume you're somewhat new to tkinter.  Button does not exist outside of tkinter, so the code snippet you posted won't work unless you import everything from the library into your namespace, which is bad practice.   Consider pasting a trimmed-down example of code that you have, which works without specifying color.

Comment: Like I said, it's bad practice to import an entire library into your namespace like that.  I'm going to add an example program to my answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: Yes you program works on python3.1 but how can i use it on python2.7 ?

Comment: like I said, I think only the case of tkinter changed.  So my example but with tkinter replaced by Tkinter.  I don't have python 2 installed to test it, but I think that's about all that changed there.

Comment: You are right that T is capital in Tkinter for python 2.7 but to import it as Tk gives error on line "root = Tk()" and says module not callable.
Also if i not import the whole package Tkinter it does'nt work

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to go back to the basics of object oriented programming.  If you imported Tkinter as Tk, then your example line needs to be root = Tk.Tk().  Importing tkinter (or Tkinter) as tk still imports the whole package, but you need to access them as members of tk rather than directly from your local namespace.

Comment: Thanks :)
the code works now fine . but was the problem only due to the import of whole module ?? because as far as i can see i have not changed any other code apart from changing the code related to import and object instantiation code. What exactly was the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Python 2.7:

import Tkinter as tk

so Tkinter with capitalized T

Comment: Python 2.7 has no module named 'tkinter' it is 'Tkinter'

Comment: in Python 2, tkinter is Tkinter.  What you import it as doesn't matter.  To follow the standard format you would use "import Tkinter as tk"